# Android onActivityResult in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, startactivityforresult

I try to get the result in a fragment. 
Code in fragment

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return

    val bundle = data?.extras
    when (requestCode) {
        LicenseActivationActivity.REQUEST_RESULT_COUNT_ENTERPRISE ->
     //
    }
}
```

This code is called. But also method onActivityResult in DrawerActivity

Do that onActivityResult is called only in the fragment?

**UPDATE**

This code in DrawerActivity

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        WayBillsActivity.start(this)
        finish()
    }
}
```

For some reason, it is also satisfied, but only after onActivityResult in fragment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onActivityResult is not being called in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment)

Comment: first it always call activity onActivityResult and from that you have to call fragment onActivityResult

Comment: remove super from method.

Comment: Yes. I do not understand where this event comes from. Value requestCode in DrawerActivity is not used anywhere in the application.

Answer (score 6):

in your Activity call this

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Then call in fragment

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); comment this unless you 

 }
```

Comment: It worked for me correctly! I used this in kotlin. Source code was like this:         
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        for (fragment in supportFragmentManager.fragments) {
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
    }

Comment: This is working for me

Answer (score 2):

add code in Drawer activity

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
   fragment.super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

}

   **fragment.super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)**
```

Then your `onActivityResult` method of fragment called

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems good in the code. Have you checked with the debugger because I have implemented the same in my fragment and it's working fine

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case REQ_CODE_EDIT_PROFILE:
                    userModel = data.getExtras().getParcelable(UserModel.class.getSimpleName());
                    setData();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

onActivityResult in fragment is called only after such method in activity. If you want handle result only on activity or only in fragment - maybe it will be better to use different result codes for different situation (if I understand your problem correctly)